# Does wrapping lists in collections make them read-only?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, binding

I have a database controller class that creates a couple of table adapters and a dataset. Also, I've created a model for each table row and I create an `ObservableCollection<MembersModel>` with model instances for each row.

```
private ObservableCollection<DoubleTeamModel> _doubleTeams = new ObservableCollection<DoubleTeamModel>();
foreach (UsersDataSet.Double_TeamsRow row in ds.Double_Teams)
{
    _doubleTeams.Add(new DoubleTeamModel(row));
}
```

In my viewmodel I have a function that returns a BindingList

```
public BindingList<TeamMatchModel> TeamQualificationMatches
{
    get 
    {
        return new BindingList<TeamMatchModel>(App.Data.GetDoubleTeamMatches().Where(
            match => match.TournamentId == CurrentTournament.Id &&
                     match.Status == MatchStatus.QualificationsPlaying).ToList<TeamMatchModel>());
    }
}
```

This BindingList is then bound to a datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrTeamQualificationMatches" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5,10,5,10"
    ItemsSource="{Binding TeamQualificationMatches, Mode=TwoWay}"
    CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
    SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
    RowStyle="{DynamicResource EditableRows}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource EditableTableCells}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team A" Binding="{Binding TeamANames, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    CellStyle="{DynamicResource ScoreATableCells}" Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Highest shot 1" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TeamANameA}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding HighestShotTeamAPlayerA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        // Some other columns
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This causes a `InvalidOperationException` with this message:

```
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'TeamQualificationMatches' of type 'CompetitionAgent.ViewModel.TournamentViewModel'
```

The grid should be writeable (Mode=TwoWay), but each column that's supposed to be read-only has it's mode set to OneWay. When did the entire collection become read-only according to the exception?

Comment: It means that your property has only getter and no setter but you try to bind both ways

Comment: Okay, but I don't need a setter for the those properties.
Should I create one anyway for the sake of binding or is there another / smarter way?

Comment: Why do you need to bind two way? `DataGrid` does not change its `ItemsSource`

Comment: Well, it's true that I am binding to individual properties of each item, In theory a change in the grid means a change in the item, and not the ItemsSource. Will try that, thanks

Comment: If that's what you're asking for then you don't need to bind `ItemsSource` both ways in order for `DataGrid` do work both ways. That bit you specify against column bindings or by using `IsReadOnly` either against whole `DataGrid` or column.